# Differential sectors of weird geometric shapes

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, circles

Consider the shape r=θ
[image: Differential sector]

At a certain angle θ from the origin, the length of the radius is θ and the angle is incremented by dθ, resulting in the second side being θ+dθ in length.

What is the correct approximation of the third side?
Also what is the precise value of the alpha angle? Or is there a function to predict its value at θ?

For instance, the differential element of a circle is:[image]

The third side is rdθ in length

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: For circles the differential sector tends to be like rectangular strips, ie the alpha angle is 90. What is the alpha angle for this shape?

Comment: Can you show your attempts so far?

Comment: 1) **"weird"** geometric shape ? There are more weird things than that... 2) Take $\Delta \theta=\pi/20$ (for example), then obtain by recurrence the lengths of the hypothenuses of these thin right triangles by using Pythagoras theorem.

Comment: Yes intuitively using limits I see that Alpha must equal 90. Does this mean that $1/2∫θ√(2θdθ)=π^3/6$
Since area of the shape$(π^3/6)=$ summation of the areas under each differential segment $=1/2*base*height$

Comment: What are you look for ultimately : $\alpha$ as a function of $\mathrm{d}\theta$ or simply $\displaystyle \lim_{\mathrm{d}\theta\to0} \alpha$ ? Or something else ?

Comment: The second value(it's probably 90)and the implication of it's implied formula, $1/2∫x√(2xdx)=n^3/6$ (from 0 to n)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the polar function, $f(\theta) = \theta $

The differential length of the graph of this function is given by

$ (ds)^2 = f^2 d\theta^2 + ( d f) ^2  $

So that the length of the curve between $\theta_1 $ and $\theta_2 $ is

$ L = \displaystyle \int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2} \sqrt{ f^2 + \left(\dfrac{df}{d\theta} \right) ^2 } d \theta $

But in differential form (which is your question), the differential length is

$ d s = \sqrt{ f^2 + \left( \dfrac{df}{d\theta} \right)^2 } d \theta = \sqrt{ \theta^2 + 1 } \ d\theta $

Comment: Elementary trigonometry then gives that $\alpha = \pi - \arctan \theta$.

Comment: Thank you. Just one follow up question. How can the area of the entire shape be represented as a function of the sector?

Comment: That's an interesting question that I have no answer for.